# Copy of "Mit Heidegger gegen Heidegger denken" by Jurgen Habermas available?

Tags: heidegger, essay

I am looking for a copy of the essay "Mit Heidegger gegen Heidegger denken" by Jurgen Habermas, in the Frankfurter Allgemeinen Zeitung (FAZ), 1953. Sort of hard to come by, especially as the FAZ does not have its archives open so far back. Would appreciate it if sb could make a copy of the article available.

Comment: German or English? And does it have to be a copy of the original article or can it be a reprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: The actual orignal article will be hard to find online. It should be available physically and/or digitalised in any decent German state library (Staatsbibliothek).

That said, as you can read [here](https://www.academia.edu/36360233/Bibliography_of_J%C3%BCrgen_Habermas_1951_2021) in an excellent bibliography on Academia.edu, there are some reprints available:

> **German**:
> “Martin Heidegger: Zur Veröffentlichung von Vorlesungen aus dem Jahre 1935”, in: Habermas, *Philosophisch-politische Profile* (Frankfurt a.M.: Suhrkamp, 1971), pp. 67-75 [1981-editionpp. 65-71].
> **English**: "Martin Heidegger: On the Publication of Lectures from the Year 1935
> ”, *Graduate Faculty Philosophy Journal*, vol. 6 no. 2 (1977), pp. 155-180; “Martin Heidegger: On the Publication of the Lectures of 1935”, in: Richard Wolin (ed.), *The Heidegger Controversy. A Critical Reader* (Cambridge, Mass.: MIT Press, 1993), pp. 186-197

Suhrkamp and CUP are pretty restrictive in their copyright management so that there is no legal way to obtain these sources online for free. If you need the German text, the Suhrkamp volume should be widely available for loan and partial copy in German libraries.

The journal article is available online, though, so you can download an electronic version of an English translation for free [here](https://www.pdcnet.org/gfpj/content/gfpj_1977_0006_0002_0155_0180). I found this link in a Danish collection of online resources on Habermas that can be found [here](https://www.habermasforum.dk/online-texts/articles-by-jurgen-habermas-).